# set cursor at the end of text area on button click in asp.net using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using this code to move the cursor at the end of text area on button click. The code works and i can see the cursor at the end but text area loses focus automatically on button click. In other words, when I click the button the cursor just pops out once at the end and then text area loses focus.

Below is the code i am using:

```
$.fn.selectRange = function (start, end) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();

            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            this.focus();
            range.select();
        }
    });
};

function setSelectionRange() {
    var el=document.getElementById('txt_comments');
    $(el).selectRange(el.innerHTML.length, el.innerHTML.length);
}

<asp:Button ID="editcomments" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
     Height="36px" style=" padding:5px; margin-top: 0px"   Width="72px" 
     OnClientClick="setSelectionRange();"   />
```

Comment: Is that "editcomments" button posting back to your page?  If so, then the text area that you are trying to focus is probably being re-created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with .NET, however triggering focus on another element from a click event is problematic because the click event doesn't necessarily fire after the element has itself finished with its own focus.

What's happening is the button is getting focus (you click on it), then your code gives focus to the text box, and then focus returns to the button to finish the click event.

You can try two things - first, try `return false;` at the end of your `setSelectionRange()` function - it may prevent focus from going back to the button.  If that doesn't work, try registering your function on the mouseup event instead of the click event.  That may be late enough for focus to be given up so you can put it on another element.

Comment: Thanks bro, i tried the mouseover event on text area and now its working. With button click i dont think its gonna work. If you find something to make it work on button click do post it here.